# preventDefault() not working for change event

Tags: javascript, onchange, preventdefault

Any ideas why preventDefault is not working? Here's the code below . . . Tks!

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#text1").change(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

function myFunc() {
    alert("Random, annoying alert");
}

</script>
</head>
```

Just one HTML element in the form:

```
<body>
<form name="test" method="post">
    <input name="text1" id="text1" type="text" onchange="myFunc();">
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: You probably meant `$("#text1")`

Comment: You ahve a few errors in your example, what default are your actually expecting to prevent?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the 'Random, annoying alert' from displaying? Are you assuming that myFunc() is the default that you're trying to prevent?

Comment: It's working perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/mxt2B/

Comment: @blgt but that is not what the OP wants to happen...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can’t use `preventDefault` on change events because it’s not cancelable:

```
$("#text1").change(function(e) {
    alert(e.cancelable?"Is cancelable":"Not cancelable");
});
```

The `cancelable` property is true only on events that can be prevented.

Comment: Many thanks. Sometimes it's the obvious stuff that's the most problematic!

Comment: So how can it be prevented?

Comment: @Triynko you must prevent the event that actually changes the input's `value`.

`change` signifies the end of an "input session". It indicates that something _has_ happened, not that something _is happening_. At the time `change` is fired, the `value` has already been changed.

If you want to intercept changes to the `value` of an input, you must prevent e.g. `input` or `click`, depending on input type.

Alternately, you could store the input's previous value in your own state management, and restore the value yourself following the `change` event if you don't want to keep the change.

Answer (score 2):

`preventDefault()` is to be used to prevent the default behaviour of an element, that default behaviour is baked in to your browser.

Like for instance the behaviour of an anchor tag when clicked is to initiate a sequence of events that will modify the url bar and send a http request (Overly simplistic explanation I know).

By using `evt.preventDefault(evt)` inside a click event you can stop the default behaviour so that you can do other operations before you action the behaviour, or ignore it all together.

The issue i can see with your example is that the default behaviour of `onchange` is to deselect the input box, unhighlighting it and I am not sure that is classed as an event (I am pretty sure it isn't). Not for it to be able to stop a function you have attached `onchange()`. Infact if you were to use a `preventDefault()`, `myFunc()` is exactly where it should be.

For an event to be prevented there must be a resultant output, something beyond modifying appearance. e.g. The click of an a tag, the submit of a form, scroll of a container.