# How to disable Select2 (v4) onchange while pushing values to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin (v4) to present a list of cities. When a city is chosen an ajax is executed to find all instances related to that city. I need to prevent the change method that calls the ajax when the user click a button to push all the nearest cities to the city previously chosen cause it is executing the ajax per each nearest city.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My first though was to use `preventDefault` but I'm not sure this can be done - see this question:

[preventdefault-not-working-for-change-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251955/preventdefault-not-working-for-change-event)

The `on change` event cannot be cancelled, so it cannot be prevented, it seems.

My only other idea would be to overwrite the `on change` behavour with an empty function?